# Reshape Pandas dataframe columns by block of N columns

Tags: python, pandas, stack, reshape, melt

I have 1 dataframe where blocks of columns need to be reshaped to rows.
I tried to use stack() and melt() but could not manage to find the right way.

Here is an example of what I expect:

```
data = {'id':['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], 
        'year':[20, 20, 19, 18],
        'b_A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'b_B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
        'b_C': [9, 10, 11, 12],
        'c_A': [13, 14, 15, 16],
        'c_B': [17, 18, 19, 20],
        'c_C': [21, 22, 23, 24],
        'd_A': [25, 26, 27, 28],
        'd_B': [29, 30, 31, 32],
        'd_C': [33, 34, 35, 36],
        } 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    id  year   b_A  b_B b_C c_A c_B c_C d_A d_B d_C
0   a1  20     1    5   9   13  17  21  25  29  33
1   a2  20     2    6   10  14  18  22  26  30  34
2   a3  19     3    7   11  15  19  23  27  31  35
3   a4  18     4    8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36
```

The expected result should be:

```
    id  year    origin  A   B   C
0   a1  20      b       1   5   9
1   a1  20      c       13  17  21
2   a1  20      d       25  29  33
3   a2  20      b       2   6   10
4   a2  20      c       14  18  22
5   a2  20      d       26  30  34
6   a3  19      b       3   7   11
7   a3  19      c       15  19  23
8   a3  19      d       27  31  35
9   a4  18      b       4   8   12
10  a4  18      c       16  20  24
11  a4  18      d       28  32  36
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert non columns names with `_` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then splitting columns by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id','year'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack(level=0).reset_index()
print (df1)
    id  year level_2   A   B   C
0   a1    20       b   1   5   9
1   a1    20       c  13  17  21
2   a1    20       d  25  29  33
3   a2    20       b   2   6  10
4   a2    20       c  14  18  22
5   a2    20       d  26  30  34
6   a3    19       b   3   7  11
7   a3    19       c  15  19  23
8   a3    19       d  27  31  35
9   a4    18       b   4   8  12
10  a4    18       c  16  20  24
11  a4    18       d  28  32  36
```

If need also set column `origin` is possible use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id','year'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(['origin',None], axis=1).stack(0).reset_index()
print (df1)
    id  year origin   A   B   C
0   a1    20      b   1   5   9
1   a1    20      c  13  17  21
2   a1    20      d  25  29  33
3   a2    20      b   2   6  10
4   a2    20      c  14  18  22
5   a2    20      d  26  30  34
6   a3    19      b   3   7  11
7   a3    19      c  15  19  23
8   a3    19      d  27  31  35
9   a4    18      b   4   8  12
10  a4    18      c  16  20  24
11  a4    18      d  28  32  36
```

Or use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with change order of values with `_` like `A_b` to `b_A`:

```
df.columns = [f'{"_".join(x[::-1])}' for x in df.columns.str.split('_')]
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                      stubnames=['A','B','C'],
                      i=['id','year'], 
                      j='origin', 
                      sep='_',
                      suffix=r'\w+').reset_index()
print (df1)
    id  year origin   A   B   C
0   a1    20      b   1   5   9
1   a1    20      c  13  17  21
2   a1    20      d  25  29  33
3   a2    20      b   2   6  10
4   a2    20      c  14  18  22
5   a2    20      d  26  30  34
6   a3    19      b   3   7  11
7   a3    19      c  15  19  23
8   a3    19      d  27  31  35
9   a4    18      b   4   8  12
10  a4    18      c  16  20  24
11  a4    18      d  28  32  36
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index=["id", "year"], 
                names_to=("origin", ".value"), 
                names_sep="_")

    id  year    origin  A   B   C
0   a1  20  b   1   5   9
1   a2  20  b   2   6   10
2   a3  19  b   3   7   11
3   a4  18  b   4   8   12
4   a1  20  c   13  17  21
5   a2  20  c   14  18  22
6   a3  19  c   15  19  23
7   a4  18  c   16  20  24
8   a1  20  d   25  29  33
9   a2  20  d   26  30  34
10  a3  19  d   27  31  35
11  a4  18  d   28  32  36
```

The `names_sep` value splits the columns; the split values that pair with `.value` remain as column headers, while the other values are lumped underneath the `origin` column.

if you want the data in order of appearance, you can use the `sort_by_appearance` parameter:

```
df.pivot_longer(
    index=["id", "year"],
    names_to=("origin", ".value"),
    names_sep="_",
    sort_by_appearance=True,
)


    id  year    origin  A   B   C
0   a1  20  b   1   5   9
1   a1  20  c   13  17  21
2   a1  20  d   25  29  33
3   a2  20  b   2   6   10
4   a2  20  c   14  18  22
5   a2  20  d   26  30  34
6   a3  19  b   3   7   11
7   a3  19  c   15  19  23
8   a3  19  d   27  31  35
9   a4  18  b   4   8   12
10  a4  18  c   16  20  24
11  a4  18  d   28  32  36
```